# Создать векторное изображение из загруженного xml файла

Tags: android, xml, imageview

1. Есть ли теоретическая возможность из загруженного xml файла установить изображение для ImageView?
2. Если первый вопрос возможен, подскажите как это сделать. Стопнулся на этапе загрузки файла.

```
File newFile = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "ic_button_invoice.xml");
Uri contentUri = getUriForFile(this, getPackageName(), newFile);
InputStream is = null;
try {
  is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(contentUri); 
  **???**
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

xml-файл выглядит так:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="1200dp"
    android:height="1200dp"
    android:viewportWidth="1200"
    android:viewportHeight="1200">
  <path
      android:fillColor="#FF000000"
      android:pathData="M1004.24,99.15l-611.44,611.44L194.49,512.29L0,706.78l198.3,198.31l195.76,195.76L588.56,906.35L1200,294.92L1004.24,99.15z"/>
</vector>
```

xml загружен успешно и парсится на ура.

Comment: Выглядит как сильно «испорченный» SVG.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, в целом так оно и есть. Разработчики Андроида почему-то решили взять куски из стандарта SVG  и сотворить из них свой велосипед.

Comment: Нашёл вот такое [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33312157/create-vectordrawable-from-string-path/49920860#49920860)